# Photoshop locking images

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Everytime I open an image in photoshop, it locks the image. 
Its slightly annoying and wonder if there is an option to prevent this

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by “locking the image”?. When you open a flat image (say, a JPG file) its whole contents appears on the automatically created Background Layer which always has locked position, transparency, blending mode, and blending options.

Comment: @Const I think you should post this as an answer. Even if it's not the answer the OP needs (although it sounds like it), it could be helpful for someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open a flat image (say, a JPG file) its whole contents appears on the automatically created Background Layer which always has locked position, transparency, blending mode, and blending options because Background is never allowed to have transparent pixels.

To “unlock” the Background you have to turn it into a “usual” layer: on the `Layers` panel double-click the Background, rename it to your liking in the newly appeared window (or just leave the name *Layer0*), and hit `OK`.